# Reestablecer cronómetro sin que empiece automáticamente, al darle al botón de stop

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código y quiero que cuando le doy al botón start y cambie a stop se reestablezca el cronómetro sin que empiece automáticamente.

```js
var startTime = 0
var start = 0
var end = 0
var diff = 0
var timerID = 0
function chrono(){
    end = new Date()
    diff = end - start
    diff = new Date(diff)
    var msec = diff.getMilliseconds()
    var sec = diff.getSeconds()
    var min = diff.getMinutes()
    var hr = diff.getHours()-1
    if (min < 10){
        min = "0" + min
    }
    if (sec < 10){
        sec = "0" + sec
    }
    if(msec < 10){
        msec = "00" +msec
    }
    else if(msec < 100){
        msec = "0" +msec
    }
    document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + ":" + msec
    timerID = setTimeout("chrono()", 10)
}
function chronoStart(){
    document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "stop!"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStop
    document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoReset
    start = new Date()
    chrono()
}
function chronoContinue(){
    document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "stop!"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStop
    document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoReset
    start = new Date()-diff
    start = new Date(start)
    chrono()
}
function chronoReset(){
    document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = "0:00:00:000"
    start = new Date()
}
function chronoStopReset(){
    document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = "0:00:00:000"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoStart
}
function chronoStop(){
    document.chronoForm.startstop.value = "start!"
    document.chronoForm.startstop.onclick = chronoContinue
    document.chronoForm.reset.onclick = chronoStopReset
    clearTimeout(timerID)
}
```

```html
<span id="chronotime">0:00:00:00</span>
<form name="chronoForm">
    <input type="button" name="startstop" value="start!" onClick="chronoStart()" />
    <input type="button" name="reset" value="reset!" onClick="chronoReset()" />
</form>
```

Comment: En lugar de repetir una y otra vez los mismo, pulsa en [edit] y explica cuál es el problema con el código actual. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Recuerda que tu pregunta no debe parecer [un ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433). Por último, al crear un snippet, en la sección de JS no es necesario agregar la etiqueta `<script>` (como cuando el código está incluido en un html).

Comment: No se entiende qué es lo que pides. `quiero que cuando le doy al botón start y cambie a stop se reestablezca el cronómetro sin que empiece automáticamente`. En el ejemplo que colocaste, cuando le das al boton stop, el cronometro no empieza automáticamente. Si bien no se reestablece, no arranca. Lo que quieres es que al presionar stop, se vuelva a cero?

Comment: Claro, que vuelva a 0 y que arranque devuelta cuando le de a start

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que pides, pero si quieres que al darle stop se vuelva a cero, añade esta línea en la función chronoStop         document.getElementById("chronotime").innerHTML = "0:00:00:000"

Comment: probre con tu codigo, y esta bien, vuelve a 0, pero cuando pongo en start devuelta no empieza de 0 empieza desde el segundo que toque stop

Comment: yo quiero que haga stop y se reestablezca a 0